# Accessing SQL Server in Windows XP Mode Virtual Pc

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, windows-xp-mode

I have a laptop running 64bit Windows 7 Ultimate. I created a Virtual PC using Microsoft XP Mode. I've installed SQL Server 2000 on the Virtual Machine.

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on the Windows 7 machine (laptop). I can browse to the SQL 2000 instance (it sees it), but I cannot successfully connect using either Windows or SQL Server Authentication. I don't get an error, the attempt just times out.

I have the Windows XP Mode Firewall turned off, and there doesn't appear to be anything in the Event logs either.

Any ideas how I can query the XP Mode SQL Server from the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Maybe the VM is only running when you're actively using it, so maybe try open up a program window in the virtual XP? Microsoft does setup an internal network to access the virtual machine through remote desktop, but maybe it does not support named pipes. Try connecting through TCP using the IP of the virtual XP instead of machine name.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to access a SQL instance that's running inside a VM from the host machine I set up a loopback adapter on both the VM and the host, set static IP addresses for each that are in the same network, then access the SQL instance using the loopback IP for the VM. If you need to access the SQL instance in the VM by name (e.g. for replication related work) then you can add the name and IP of the VM to the host machine's host file.